# Need regex code to match a word with one character difference

Tags: regex

The word which i have to match is  **"FFM_L_REEF_30"** (the length of the word will not be fixed)
The list of words where i have to match is
**"FFM_H_REEF_40"

"FFM_H_REEF_50"

"FFM_L_REEF_20"

"FFM_L_RAEF_30"**

is it possible to write a regular expression where it can match the words with only one character difference, like 
**"FFM_L_REEF_20" - In this number 3 is changed to 2

"FFM_L_QEEF_30" - In this character R is changed to Q**

QUESTION EDITED

Comment: That's quite the edit - totally different question ;) What environment are you working in? Programming language? I think that you'll need to write one explicit regex for each unique word which is really impractical so I believe a levenshtein calculation should be the way to go.

Comment: To illustrate how impractical (I believe) regex would be here, [check this regex101 example](https://www.regex101.com/r/R0DFoE/1).

Comment: There are some linear algorithms to check single char difference. Take a look at the code from http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/479324/178988. Sorry, I'm not ready to translate description to English, but hope that the code can be useful anyway. Code at the end of [this answer](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/479325/178988) is simple enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a JS example of how you can solve it using the Levenshtein algorithm.

(Note that the `getEditDistance` method is copied from [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance), where there are implementations for a multitude of programming languages).

```js
var testWord = "FFM_L_REEF_30",
    wordList = [
      "FFM_H_REEF_40",
      "FFM_H_REEF_50",
      "FFM_L_REEF_20",
      "FFM_L_RAEF_30",
      "A rendom sentence",
      testWord,
      "FFM_L_REEF_3"
  ],
  w;

function getEditDistance(a, b) {

 // Code from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance

 if (a.length === 0) return b.length;
 if (b.length === 0) return a.length;

 var matrix = [];

 // increment along the first column of each row
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i <= b.length; i++) {
  matrix[i] = [i];
 }

 // increment each column in the first row
 var j;
 for (j = 0; j <= a.length; j++) {
  matrix[0][j] = j;
 }

 // Fill in the rest of the matrix
 for (i = 1; i <= b.length; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= a.length; j++) {
   if (b.charAt(i - 1) == a.charAt(j - 1)) {
    matrix[i][j] = matrix[i - 1][j - 1];
   } else {
    matrix[i][j] = Math.min(matrix[i - 1][j - 1] + 1, // substitution
          Math.min(matrix[i][j - 1] + 1, // insertion
             matrix[i - 1][j] + 1)); // deletion
   }
  }
 }

 return matrix[b.length][a.length];
};

wordList.forEach(function (w) {
 var ld = getEditDistance(w, testWord);

 document.write('<p style="color:' + (ld>1?'red':'green') + ';">"' + w + '" gives levenshtein distance ' + ld + '</p>');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to the below regex.

```
^(?:(.)\1*(?:(?!\1).)\1*|(.)(?:(?!\2)(.))\3*$)$
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/fnbav4/1)

Let me know the case where the above regex fails.

Comment: Or the same but a bit shorter (2 redundant non-capturing groups removed): `^(?:(.)\1*(?!\1).\1*|(.)(?!\2)(.)\3*)$`.

Comment: Hi the question is edited. Now i have given a more appropriate scenario of my case

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ya, I added unnecessary non-cap group .. It's just for understanding purpose..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. You can use the next regex:
`a*.a*`
It means that your string contains any number of 'a', then one any symbol, and again any number of 'a'.
'.' means any symbol except of '\n'. If you also want the string will contain '\n', you can use the next regex:
`a*[\s\S]a*`

Comment: Hi the question is edited. Now i have given a more appropriate scenario of my case
Thanks for the help.